# Python: False vs 0

Tags: python, int, boolean

In PHP you use the `===` notation to test for `TRUE` or `FALSE` distinct from `1` or `0`.

For example `if FALSE == 0` returns `TRUE`, `if FALSE === 0` returns `FALSE`. So when doing string searches in base 0 if the position of the substring in question is right at the beginning you get `0` which PHP can distinguish from `FALSE`.

Is there a means of doing this in Python?

Comment: you _can_ distinguish, but you usually shouldn't have to.  `False` looks like `0` in almost every way (and `True` like `1`).  e.g. `True + True + True + False == 3`

Comment: a very good point ... although there are cases where you do want to distinguish

Comment: @mgilson I don't usually have to distinguish. However, in this case I am looking to validate a hex color string. So I am first checking for the # symbol at the beginning of the string and then checking the length. I want to be able to tell the user at the time they pass in the color value that it is invalid, not wait until later when the class attempts to use it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Python,

- The `is` operator tests for identity (`False is False`, `0 is not False`).
- The `==` operator which tests for logical equality (and thus `0 == False`).

Technically neither of these is exactly equivalent to PHP's `===`, which compares logical equality and type - in Python, that'd be `a == b and type(a) is type(b)`.

Some other differences between `is` and `==`:

#### Mutable type literals

- `{} == {}`, but `{} is not {}` (and the same holds true for lists and other mutable types)
- However, if `a = {}`, then `a is a` (because in this case it's a reference to the same instance)

#### Strings

- `"a"*255 is not "a"*255"`, but `"a"*20 is "a"*20` in most implementations, due to how Python handles string interning. This behavior isn't guaranteed, though, and you probably shouldn't be using `is` in this case. `"a"*255 == "a"*255` and is almost always the right comparison to use.

#### Numbers

- `12345 is 12345` but `12345 is not 12345 + 1 - 1` in most implementations, similarly. You pretty much always want to use equality for these cases.

Comment: I use `is` and `is not` all the time for None. Never occurred to me to use it for True and False. Duh. Thanks, this works for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
if something is False:
```

is what you should do

```
if something is None:
```

also works

the moral is use `is`  ... (although you should **never** do `something is 123457`, or simillar)

for why you should never do this with ints and things see http://ideone.com/iKmWCn

Answer (score 0):

The strict equivalent of `x === y` in Python is `type(x) is type(y) and x == y`. You don't really want to do this as Python is duck typed. If an object has the appropriate method or attribute then you shouldn't be too worried about its actual type.

If you are checking for a specific unique object such as (`True`, `False`, `None`, or a class) then you should use `is` and `is not`. For example: `x is True`.