# Python numpy change 0 to -1 without changing False to -1

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have a numpy array with values varying from booleans to decimal and real numbers. I get this data from a database which means that when a field is missing it returns a 0. I want to change all zeros to a -1, all Falses to 0 and Trues to 1. It seems however that Python can't make the distinction between False and 0, thus changing both to 1. This is what I have tried:

```
X[X==0] = -1
X[X==False] = 0
X[X==True] =1
```

The result is all zeros and all Falses are both changed to -1. How would I fix this?

edit:
This is a sample of my array:

```
[[0.03829744 0.0 True False True True 6.0]
[0.0 0.0 True False True True 6.0]
[0.09174341 0.0 True False True True 6.0]
[0.03489284 2 0 True True False 0 6.0]]
```

I would want all 0.0 values to be -1, all False values to be 0 and all True values to be 1.

edit 2: looping over all values works but there must be a more elegant solution

```
for i in xrange(X.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(X.shape[1]):
        if X[i,j] == 0.0 and type(X[i, j]) == float:
            X[i][j] = -1
```

Comment: a `np.array` only contains data from same type. So if you put a `bool` with an `int` it will cast the `bool` to an `int`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: False vs 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431249/python-false-vs-0)

Comment: @SiHa While that's a great link it's not really relevant to this Numpy issue.

Comment: You should post a _small_ sample array of typical values into your question.

Comment: @PM2Ring. Oh, sorry. Not terribly familiar with Numpy. But using `is False` can be used to disinguish `False` from `0` still, no?

Comment: @PM2Ring I included a sample array!

Comment: @SiHa Certainly! But that won't help if Numpy has already converted the values. FWIW, if you have two different Numpy array members that are equal to zero they won't (usually) have the same id (so an `is` test between them would result in `False`); that'd be impossible in plain Python.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Your example "array" has conflicting types (could be explained), and the last row has 8 elements while the others have 7. Please try to come up with data that makes sense, and test your example data before posting.

Comment: What is the dtype and shape of your array; it might help if you print the `repr` of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy arrays are most efficient if they are homogeneous, or at least if they have a fixed type pattern associated with them. You can only hold your ragtag collection of values in a numpy array of `dtype=object`, which is possibly the least efficient thing you can do with numpy.

Correspondingly, there aren't efficient (native numpy) methods (that I know of) that let you access the type of each of the elements. This is simply not something that usually comes up when using numpy.

So the only way that I can think of to make your code more elegant is to transform the double loop into function calls. I will use `map`, which is probably still not as fast as a native numpy function would be (since the latter would be compiled in C), but it's possibly faster than the python double loop, and clearer as well.

One note, however, which I also noted in a comment: your example data is not rectangular, i.e. it can't be converted to a 2d numpy array, however hard you try. I assumed that you made a mistake when putting together the MCVE, and omitted one element from the fourth line of your example data (thereby making your array `(4,7)` in shape).

```
import numpy as np

# dummy data as nested list, make sure it's rectangular
datlist = [[0.03829744, 0.0, True, False, True, True, 6.0],
           [0.0, 0.0, True, False, True, True, 6.0],
           [0.09174341, 0.0, True, False, True, True, 6.0],
           [0.03489284, 0, True, True, False, 0, 6.0]]  #dropped an element here

# create a numpy array of dtype object from datlist
dat = np.array(datlist,dtype=object)
```

I gathered from your example that this is your starting point. Now, what I'd do is define a function that checks the value and type of an element of the array, and returns -1 for non-bool zeros. This function can then be `map`ped to your array, making use of `.ravel()` to access the entire data range:

```
def zeroswap(elem):
    # replace non-bool zeros with -1, leave the rest alone
    return -1 if elem==0 and elem is not False else elem

dat.ravel()[:] = list(map(zeroswap,dat.ravel())) #list() needed for python3
```

The resulting array looks like this:

```
array([[0.03829744, -1, True, False, True, True, 6.0],
       [-1, -1, True, False, True, True, 6.0],
       [0.09174341, -1, True, False, True, True, 6.0],
       [0.03489284, -1, True, True, False, -1, 6.0]], dtype=object)
```

As you see, both float and integer zeros have been transformed to -1. This is what makes sense to me, and it is due to the fact that we only checked for non-`False` zeros. If you want to distinguish the two kinds of numerical zeros, you can easily do that in the `zeroswap` function. If you want to switch the bool values, you can also do that. Here's an upgraded function that will transform `0.0 -> -1`, `0 -> -1`, `False -> 0`, `True -> 1`, `other -> other`:

```
def zeroswap(elem):
    if type(elem) is bool:
        return int(elem)
    elif elem==0:
        return -1
    else:
        return elem
```

You can play around calling this function to various elements to make sure that it does what you expect it to do. The bottom line is that you should `map` this function over the ravelled version of your array, that lets you operate without having to know the dimensionality of your array.