# How can I check that a variable is 0.0 and not False?

Tags: python

I need to distinguish when a variable is 0.0 specifically, so `a == 0` will not work because it will fail when `a` is equal to False. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431249/python-false-vs-0 not a duplicate though because of the float issue

Comment: I'm interested in why exactly you need to make the distinction. It suggests that the design can be improved.

Comment: It's actually just for a programming challenge, identifying 0's in an array that includes items like 0, 0.0, False, "0", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = 0.0
if a == 0.0 and isinstance(a, float):
    print('a is 0.0')
```

Or a bit less strict (doesn't care if `a` is not a floating value):

```
a = 0
if a == 0 and a is not False:
    print('a is zero')
```

Comment: Note that `a == 0 and a is not False` can be chained with `0 == a is not False`.

Comment: @blhsing TBH that doesn't look like an improvement, I'm still trying to parse in my head _why_ that would work, you'd need to know by heart the operator precedence rules. Let's not sacrifice readability for typing less code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the variables type, to specify its the correct data-type that you want. The `type(a)` function will return a class, and then `type(a).__name__` will give you the string form.

Answer (score 0):

You can check both `type` and value of that variable. For example if you want to check if `a == 0.0` specially you can use:

```
if type(a) != bool and a == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use short circuit trickery with `is`:

```
if (a and False) is not False:
   # ...
```

or

```
if not(a or a is False):
   # ...
```